# Spring - Dependency Injection - which takes precedence?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I know there are 3 ways to do Dependency Injection using Spring : field, setter and constructor Injection.

But say we have more all 3 in the same Component, like so :

```
import base.service.FortuneService;

@Component
public class FootballCoach implements Coach {
    
    //Field Injection
    @Autowired
    private FortuneService fortuneService;
    
    //setter Injection
    @Autowired
    public void setFortuneService(FortuneService fortuneService) {
        this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
    }
    //constructor Injection
    @Autowired
    public FootballCoach(FortuneService fortuneService) {
        this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
    }
}
```

Which one takes precedence - so to say? Will Spring just do all 3 and overwrite the `fortuneService` field two times? If so, which is the last one standing? Or will only one dependency injection be chosen?

I ran the code above without problems and I got the following logs, but I don't really know how to read them.

Note: `FortuneService` is an interface and I have a `HappyFortuneService` class that implements it.

```
Sep 10, 2020 11:40:44 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry getSingleton
FINE: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'footballCoach'
Sep 10, 2020 11:40:44 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry getSingleton
FINE: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'happyFortuneService'
Sep 10, 2020 11:40:44 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver createArgumentArray
FINE: Autowiring by type from bean name 'footballCoach' via constructor to bean named 'happyFortuneService'
Sep 10, 2020 11:40:44 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry getSingleton
FINE: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'tennisCoach'
Sep 10, 2020 11:40:44 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver createArgumentArray
FINE: Autowiring by type from bean name 'tennisCoach' via constructor to bean named 'happyFortuneService'
```

Comment: Well constructor must take precedence over the other two, because you can't set a field or call a method on nothing.

Comment: "*Will Spring just do all 3*" Put a breakpoint in the setter. That will give you your answer. I assume so yes. Of course the **real** answer is "*don't do this in the first place*"

Comment: Inject the same thing at three places into the same object is useless.

Comment: @Michael OK, so the constructor is the first one called, that I can understand, and a bean is created. But then the other 2 are called. Do two new beans get created when the field and setter injection happen that then overwrite the first bean ? If so, in what order ?

Comment: No bean gets created as a result of @Autowired. The clue is in the name: *wiring*. It is just connecting existing things together. In this is example, you are just assigning the field with the same `FortuneService` instance 3 times. Again, easily testable. Put a breakpoint in the constructor of that service

Comment: Why not to just add `System.out.println()` statements to each block (possibly printing the field as a first statement in constructor) and see it yourself?

Comment: @Michael Oh, so in the constructor a singleton bean `happyFortuneService` is created and then all the `@Autowire` does is point to the same bean 2 more times ?

Comment: No, that is wrong and not what I said. Please go and read the documentation about how this works. It is extremely extensive.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I can do this for the setter and constructor Injection, but I cannot do it for the Field Injection.

Comment: As I said, you can *print the field as a first statement in your constructor*, and thus, you will see whether the field is injected before constructor or not. Rest assured, that setter runs after constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For starters don't do things like that.

That being said the following will happen, in order:

1. It will call the constructor with an instance of `FortuneService`, because the object needs to be constructed first, before anything else can happen.
2. It will inject the fields annotated with `@Autowired` with an instance of `FortuneService`
3. It will call the methods annotated with `@Autowired` with an instance of `FortuneService`

Now depending on the scope of the `FortuneService`, it will either inject a singleton (the default) or create a new instance (when the bean is prototype scoped).

**NOTE:** The ordering can be deduced from the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L462) of the [`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). That the constructor is called is logical but the ordering of field vs. method is coming from the `buildAutowiringMetadata` method. It detects first the fields then the methods.

Comment: I was just about to add that to the question. It is in the source of the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and the fact that the constructor needs to be called first is just plain java (without an object instance there is no way to reflectively set a field or call a method).

Comment: Nice, though it seems unlike Spring to not mention explicitly in the documentation. I guess you shouldn't be relying on it really, so maybe they consider it an impl detail.