# NullPointerException of JDBC Template in DAO Constructor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, autowired, spring-jdbc

I am new to Spring Boot and was trying to implement the below code for Spring Boot JDBC. I am getting a NullPointerException in the `this.jdbcTemplate` in the `UserDao` constructor while running the application. I think the error is because the `UserDao` constructor is being called before the instantiation of `JdbcTemplate.` Is that correct?
I haven't come across this error until now where the `@Autowired` cannot resolve the dependencies. Can someone please elaborate upon the reason for the error?

**SpringBootDatabaseApplication.java**

```
package com.mrityu.springbootdatabase;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDatabaseApplication {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDatabaseApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**UserDao.java**

```
package com.mrityu.springbootdatabase;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class UserDao {
   @Autowired
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   public UserDao() {
        String query = "create table if not exists User(id int primary key, name varchar(200))";
        int update = this.jdbcTemplate.update(query);
        System.out.println("Constructor Called: " + update);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to run the code, but you're trying to use the uninitialized jdbcTemplate field in your constructor.
Constructor base injection should do the trick

```
public UserDao(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {...}
```

Otherwise, you can still use field injection and move your logic into a method.

```
public void yourMethod() {
    String query = "create table if not exists User(id int primary key, name varchar(200))";
    int update = this.jdbcTemplate.update(query);
    System.out.println("Method Called: " + update);
}
```

In your case, it's about how java initializes classes, not spring boot auto wiring.

You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63826401/8285132) for the dependency injection precedence.